# How to add members to group by using msgraph-sdk-ruby？

Tags: ruby, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developping original mailing system by using microsoftgraph and ruby on rails.
During development, I found msgraph-sdk-ruby, and think it help me develop.
But now, I am troubled not knowing how to add members to group by using this sdk.

Could anyone help me?

I think I can make it like this...

```rb
graph.groups.find('group-id').members.create~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out.

```rb
data = {'@odata.id': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}'}.to_json
@graph.service.post('/groups/{id}/members/$ref', data)
```